# Does CPU and RAM affect MTP file transfer speed android?

Tags: mtp

I am testing an application for file transfer using MTP the transfer speed is getting vary in different android devices. Can anyone help me to know what are the factors that may affect the MTP file transfer speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number one factor in transfer speed is the actual R/W speed of the phone's internal NAND chip.